# firebase ssl generation takes over 24 hours and hosting status shows needs setup

Tags: firebase, dns, hosting, web-hosting, firebase-hosting

```
hunbalsiddiqui.com. 599 IN  A   50.63.202.52
hunbalsiddiqui.com. 599 IN  A   151.101.1.195
hunbalsiddiqui.com. 599 IN  A   151.101.65.195
```

I followed the firebase official docs and added txt records and A A ips on my dns records, its been almost 24 hours but my hosting status this shows needs setup.

Although my domain i.e hunbalsiddiqui.com is redirecting me to my website but it shows not secure because SSL certificate is not provisioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal that adding your site to a certificate may take some time, and that this does not necessarily happen at exactly the same time as when the DNS records propagate.

I just now checked the domain in your question, and don't see any warnings about the SSL certificate. So it looks like both DNS propagation and adding it to the certificate were completed.

If you continue see the `complete setup` instructions in the Firebase Hosting console, check with a tool like https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/ to see if the `TXT` and `A` records have propagated yet. If they have, and the Firebase console still says that you need to complete the setup, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.